# Python won't allow custom package to be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a python script located on my desktop as well as a package I made called testpackage. It contains three scripts each containing one function which prints a word. Here is a sample of one of the scripts.

```
def dog():
    print ("Dog")
```

I also have an `__init__.py`  file and contains the following.

```
import sys, os
pathVar = os.path.normpath('/Desktop/testpackage')
from cat import *
from dog import *
from horse import *
```

The file on my desktop, named myFile.py, contains the following

```
from testpackage import dog
dog.dog()
```

When I run this script, I get an error along the lines of

> File 'myFile.py", line1, in  from testpackage import dog. File "C:\Users\User\Deskop\testpackage__init__.py", line 3 in 
>   from cat import *
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'cat'

I have tried every trick under the sun that i've found on google so I'm wondering why it can't locate the script from the `__init__` file.

Comment: does it answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I wasnt using the correct command to insert the path.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the module's parent dir in PYTHONPATH.

You can achieve this using the following code:

```
import sys
module_dir = r"/path/to/module/parent/dir"  
sys.path.insert(0, module_dir)
# assuming module is named my_mod.py
import my_mod
```